# Tips for golfing a fibonacci sequence generator

Tags: code-golf, tips, c

One day in July 2020, I made the following C program:

```c
#define A m]
a[9999],*m=a;main(){for(2[A=4[A=1;;){for(;4[A;putchar(6[m-=3]+48));
for(puts(a);7[A;2[A=4[A,4[A=1)if(4[A+=3[m+=3]-1,9<(3[A=2[A+=3[A))++
5[A,7[A=1,3[A-=10;}}
```

with three superfluous newlines removed, it's 167 bytes and it prints the fibonacci sequence (as decimal numbers, separated with newline) potentially infinitely (it *will* crash when exceeding the buffer size after printing many terms of the sequence). [Try it online (gcc)!](https://tio.run/##LYvBDsIgEETvfkUTL6xAIqVam5UD30E4EGyVA9VUPZl@O26tm@xmduZNlNcYS9le@iGNfWWr7DfBdTRe7LIJmEMaGXyG@8RqZ01DqxBXA@nDx/sVb2FiR5el0Z43JwBcUgqeLAC2BP2r4leHNDAS3GiX6XipRHdmmqJ6dS0A5wfC2wUXZEij9jjPpXwB) [Try it online (clang)!](https://tio.run/##LYvBDoIwEETvfgWJl65tEwsokrWHfkfTQ4MgTWw1qCfDt9dF3GQ3szNvOtndfLrmvL30Q0h9YYroNt62NE7sovYYfUgMPsN9YqU1uqZViKuB9OHj/epGP7GjjVJXjtcnAFxSCp7MAzYE/aviV4cwMBJcVzbScVKJ9swqisrVNQCcHwhvFlyQIbXa4zzn/AU).

As I had trouble golfing it myself, I decided to ask the C golfers of CGCC for help. The challenge is to golf it, or more formally, to produce *the same output as this program* (and of course you can derive your own solution based on it). The code should stay *reasonably* portable (i.e. not perform out-of-bounds accesses before program termination is desired, use compiler extensions, etc...).

Your program is expected to print at least `15939` consecutive fibonacci numbers, starting from the smallest, separated with newlines, printed as decimal numbers, starting with `0 1 1 2 3 5 ...`.

Your answer might also provide improvements to the original version as an extra (printing more sequence terms with minimally more bytes, etc... - just make sure to post the golfed version *with* your answer, because it's the main goal of this question).

Comment: :O I like the `[A` trick

Comment: @Wzl i'm also a fan of the puts trick - puts appends a newline after the text it prints. assume `int v[] = {0, blablabla};` - the 0 will always be the first element of an array:
`putchar('\n') => putchar(10); => puts(""); => puts(v);`

Comment: Can you post an ungolfed (easier to read) version of the code, so we may more easily see your algorithmic approach?

Comment: I assume the a[] array stores every term of the sequence.  Is this storage necessary, or do you just need to print the terms as they are generated?

Comment: Can you use external bigint libraries?  e.g. [libgmp](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: no, any external libraries are not allowed. that makes the challenge trivial.

Answer (score 3):

## 142 bytes (-25)

3 more bytes saved by [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
a[9999]={0,1},i=2,k,s;main(c){for(;i--;c&&putchar(i?k+48:10))c|=k=a[i]>>4;for(;c=s>9,++i<9999;a[i]=k<<4|s%10)s=a[i]/16+c+(k=a[i]&15);main(c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3bCsIwEES/xpCQFBuJYt1s/JDSh7CgLsELjT61/fbYVpzXOWeGqitRKbFt5nQ41MZOhnFnkslwj/yQpIbLs5fAVQUkxOvzplvsJZ@TdseTrZWiERPGlrsQHKwsYQ6N0Zr9MgtLh8l7N@bNLOQV3tqDJi1/prB79b@DqZQv) (GCC)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BDsIgFERPI4EAsRg0Vvh4kKYL8hP1B62m6Krt2bGtcbbz3gxqvMfuWkps6jktDJUykyLYqaSye0TqOIrh8uy5I60dMvb6vPEWe07nJO3xZCohcIQEsaE2BOtWFiGHWklJfpl1SwfJezvmzSzkFd6ag0TJfyYze/G/c1MpXw) (clang)

---

## 145 bytes (-22)

This is a complete rewrite which can probably be golfed some more.

```c
a[9999]={0,1},i,k,s;main(c){for(i=2;;){while(i--)(c|=k=a[i]>>4)&&putchar(i?k+48:10);for(;c=s>9,++i<9999;a[i]=k<<4|s%10)s=a[i]/16+c+(k=a[i]&15);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1bDsIgFAVXYwMBYjForLfgQpp@kBu1N9RHROMHZe3Y6vmemYPqgliK75p5vU211FmSDDLC1dONIU/n@5OR3QDw9BloPDFSijOcbLC@o945w6vq8X7h4GfwGITZH3TNYfEAbXSNFILa5QAWwYa2NVNczUz8FdZ6J1Cwf67SWw45l/IF) (GCC)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BDoIwEAW/xqZN20gNGnFp/RDCodmobAporMYD8O2V6jvPzEONvR9vKfmmWtfaqVBmUaSCijB4GjmK6Xp/crI7ADF9OuovnLQWHGcbrG@oda4UjD3eL@z8Cp6DLI8nUwjIHqCNrlJSUp0PIAs21HU5x83KxF9haw4SJf/nmNkLWJaUvg) (clang)

### How?

#### Encoding

For each entry `a[i]` with `i > 0`, we store the **i**-th decimal digit of the last Fibonacci term into the bits **0** to **3** and the **i**-th decimal digit of the penultimate term into the bits **4** to **7**. (The convention used here is that the 1st decimal digit is the least significant one.)

We start with all entries set to **0** except `a[1]` which is set to **1**:

```
a[1] = 00000001
       \__/\__/
         |   |
         |   +--> first and only digit of Fib(2) = 1
         +------> first and only digit of Fib(1) = 0
```

It is then updated as follows:

```
00000001 -> 00010001 -> 00010010 -> 00100011 -> 00110101 -> ...
\__/\__/    \__/\__/    \__/\__/    \__/\__/    \__/\__/
  0   1       1   1       1   2       2   3       3   5
```

#### Printing

Each number is printed by iterating from the most significant digit to the least significant one, ignoring leading zeros and ending with a line-feed.

```c
while(i--)
  (c |= k = a[i] >> 4)
  && putchar(i ? k + 48 : 10);
```

We start with `i = 2` and `c = argc` (which is guaranteed to be greater than **0**) in order to make sure that the initial `0` is printed.

#### Updating

In order to compute the next term `Fib(n+1)`, we iterate through all values stored in `a[]`, this time from least significant to most significant. We add the last digit to the penultimate one, update each entry accordingly and keep track of the carry into `c`.

```c
for(; c = s > 9, ++i < 9999; a[i] = k << 4 | s % 10;)
  s = a[i] / 16 + c + (k = a[i] & 15);
```

We have `i = 9999` and `c = 0` at the end of this loop, which are the expected values to print the next number, starting from the 2nd iteration.

We also end up with `s = 0`, which means that `c` will be re-initialized to `0` as expected before the next update.

Comment: @ceilingcat Is it the correct link? This one core-dumps.